# Get value location from JSON

Tags: python, json

this is JSON text:

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "clientid":"None",
   "serviceid":"1232",
   "pid":"None",
   "domain":"None",
   "totalresults":1,
   "startnumber":0,
   "numreturned":1,
   "products":{
      "product":[
         {
            "id":3212,
            "clientid":2025,
            "orderid":3285,
            "ordernumber":34352,
            "pid":2,
            "regdate":"2022-08-10",
            "name":"P2",
            "translated_name":"P2",
            "groupname":"VPS",
            "translated_groupname":"VPS",
            "domain":"Mi",
            "dedicatedip":"123.456.345:22600",
            "serverid":0,
            "servername":"",
            "serverip":"None",
            "serverhostname":"None",
            "suspensionreason":"",
            "firstpaymentamount":"1.00",
            "recurringamount":"1.00",
            "paymentmethod":"Cryptocurrencies",
            "paymentmethodname":"Cryptocurrencies",
            "billingcycle":"Monthly",
            "nextduedate":"2022-09-10",
            "status":"Active",
            "username":"Admin",
            "password":"ABCD",
            "subscriptionid":"",
            "promoid":0,
            "overideautosuspend":0,
            "overidesuspenduntil":"0000-00-00",
            "ns1":"Prefix1",
            "ns2":"Prefix2",
            "assignedips":"123.345.235.66:21600",
            "notes":"example",
            "diskusage":0,
            "disklimit":0,
            "bwusage":0,
            "bwlimit":0,
            "lastupdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "customfields":{
               "customfield":[
                  {
                     "id":4,
                     "name":"Your Operating System",
                     "translated_name":"Your Operating System",
                     "value":"Windows 10 64bit"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":5,
                     "name":"Location",
                     "translated_name":"Location",
                     "value":" Falkenstein Germany"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":142,
                     "name":"ID",
                     "translated_name":"ID",
                     "value":"1234"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "configoptions":{
               "configoption":[
                  
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

this is my code:

```
            data = {
                    'identifier':identifier,
                    'secret':secret, 
                    'action': 'GetClientsProducts',
                    'serviceid':service_id,
                    'responsetype':'json',
                    } 
            r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 
            data = r.json()
            for order in data["products"]["product"]:
                name_of_server = order['name']
                print(order['name'])
                for item in order["customfields"]["customfield"]:
                    if item["name"] in 'Your Operating System':
                        OS_of_Server = item["value"] 
                        print(item["value"])
                    if item["name"] in 'Location':
                        print(item['value'])
                        ...
```

result:

P2

Windows 10 64bit

I want get value of name: Location , should be: "Falkenstein Germany"

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code

your json response

```
import json

a = """{
   "result":"success",
   "clientid":"None",
   "serviceid":"1232",
   "pid":"None",
   "domain":"None",
   "totalresults":1,
   "startnumber":0,
   "numreturned":1,
   "products":{
      "product":[
         {
            "id":3212,
            "clientid":2025,
            "orderid":3285,
            "ordernumber":34352,
            "pid":2,
            "regdate":"2022-08-10",
            "name":"P2",
            "translated_name":"P2",
            "groupname":"VPS",
            "translated_groupname":"VPS",
            "domain":"Mi",
            "dedicatedip":"123.456.345:22600",
            "serverid":0,
            "servername":"",
            "serverip":"None",
            "serverhostname":"None",
            "suspensionreason":"",
            "firstpaymentamount":"1.00",
            "recurringamount":"1.00",
            "paymentmethod":"Cryptocurrencies",
            "paymentmethodname":"Cryptocurrencies",
            "billingcycle":"Monthly",
            "nextduedate":"2022-09-10",
            "status":"Active",
            "username":"Admin",
            "password":"ABCD",
            "subscriptionid":"",
            "promoid":0,
            "overideautosuspend":0,
            "overidesuspenduntil":"0000-00-00",
            "ns1":"Prefix1",
            "ns2":"Prefix2",
            "assignedips":"123.345.235.66:21600",
            "notes":"example",
            "diskusage":0,
            "disklimit":0,
            "bwusage":0,
            "bwlimit":0,
            "lastupdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "customfields":{
               "customfield":[
                  {
                     "id":4,
                     "name":"Your Operating System",
                     "translated_name":"Your Operating System",
                     "value":"Windows 10 64bit"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":5,
                     "name":"Location",
                     "translated_name":"Location",
                     "value":" Falkenstein Germany"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":142,
                     "name":"ID",
                     "translated_name":"ID",
                     "value":"1234"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "configoptions":{
               "configoption":[
                  
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
"""
```

code to get values

```py
j_obj = json.loads(a)
for i in j_obj['products']['product']:
    print(i['name'])
    for j in i['customfields']['customfield']:
        if j['name']=='Location':
            print(j['value'])
        if j['name']=='Your Operating System':
            print(j['value'])
```